# Develop Marketplace like Alibaba using Magento (Without extension)

Tags: marketplace

I need an Honest answer about this. I have created a marketplace with Magento with paid extension and the result is very disappointing. I said the web is slow and can be taken down with 10 concurrent connection.

I would like to know If I create a marketplace with very demanding requirement like 100 000 vendors with 1000 SKUs each. Do you think it is possible for Magento to handle this kind of load? (By this, it means I have to create 100000  websites within the Magento)

Comment: I personally would say so but would recommend looking at the Enterprise edition as it has been fine tuned for this sort of level of products and customers

Comment: 10 connections means your server config is bad, magento can work with much more data and connections...

Answer (score 0):

Slowness:
- There are potentially so many reasons that can limit Magento speed. I will try to touch only a few here.

- Was Magento default installation was that slow or it became slow after installation of 3rd party module? I think, the later should be the reason; and not Magento's fault. In that case, you should contact the module's author and report the issue.
- Did you check PHP.ini? There is a limit mentioned there. If you haven't touched it, you should increase it before anything else.
- Did you check the Machine load? What's having suffocation; RAM or Processor?
- I would say you need Magento Speed Optimization as well. There are a lot of 3rd party services doing this. I have done it personally. With the help of a couple of free modules plus lot of self customization.
- What theme you are using? Is it default or 3rd party? If 3rd party, then try to REMOVE it (not just switch) and then check the speed. Most often than not; heavy themes are the culprit.
- To check the page speeds, use some page speed browser extensions that calculates and display page loading speeds.

Scaling:
- Magento Enterprise is your best bet.

- But every solution has it's limitation not only based on software but hardware as well. You need to scale the hardware as well as using solutions like load balancing, varnish, CDN, etc.
- If you choose Enterprise, I believe they provide the scaling analysis with their support.

Hope this helps you and others..

Khurram.